# Como passar um JSON Object para um metodo no webservice?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou tentando passar um JSON Object para um metodo no meu controller e não estou conseguindo, o problema é que o campo email sempre retorna nulo.

Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

**JSON Object**

```
{"UsuarioJsonModel": {"email":"meuemail@domain.com", "senha":"xxxxxx"}}
```

**Model**

```
public class UsuarioJsonModel 
{

    public long id                  { get; set; }         
    public String nome              {   get;set;}            
    public String email             {get;set;}    
    public String senha             {get;set;}   
    public int status               { get; set; } //1 ativo, 2 inativo, 0 aguardando
    public int tipo                 { get; set; } //1 painel, 2 aplicativos
    public String imagem            { get; set; }
    public int loginBy              { get; set; } //0 app, 1 facebook
    public UsuarioJsonModel() { }

}
```

**Método que recebe o JSON Object**

```
[WebMethod]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doLoginApp(UsuarioJsonModel model)
{ 
    jsonResposta.Add("status", "1");
    jsonResposta.Add("email", model.email);
    return Json(jsonResposta);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa passar um objeto que tenha as propriedades definidas no model. Da forma atual, está sendo passado um objeto com a propriedade `UsuarioJsonModel` e está propriedade que é o objeto que você precisa.

Apenas altere seu JSON para

```
{ "email":"meuemail@domain.com", "senha":"xxxxxx" }
```